# Uploading my site from XAMPP to Apache public host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

This is a general question.
I`ve compliled site in [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) and it is properly running, because lack of experience I used mysql functions rather than the improved mysqli.

Uploading my site on `ecowebhost` the site does not work, I have changed paths so that, apparently, no connection error happens. but still I cannot interact with my database. 
From the site seems that php4 version are supported, am I required to recompile my web site because of that?

this is a little sample code of what I am trying to do...

```
<?php
function connectto($tablename){
$db_host = "xxx";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_pass = "xxx";
$link = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$tablename") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
// @mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
// @mysql_select_db("$tablename") or die ("No database");
}
?>
```

Thanks

---

if I run the following

```
<?php
// connection to database
// include_once "connectto.php";
// connectto('test');
$tablename = "test";
$db_host = "xxx";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_pass = "xxx";
$link =mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$tablename") 
or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());}
else { echo " <br /><br />connection established! <br />";}
?>
```

the only error message that comes out is

Could not connect to MySQL

---

update....

I got a bit of my code working but I am struggling with finding a way to insert some values in the database...

```
<?php
$db_host = "xxxx";
$db_username = "xxxx";
$db_pass = "xxxx";
// $link = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","cl45-members-7b5") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("cl45-members-7b5") or die ("No database");
$sql ="INSERT INTO members (username, email, gps_lat, gps_long, password, skill, skill_rate,) VALUES ('a','2','3','4','5','5','6')";
    print '<br /><br /> Great! now you are registered; now update your profile <br />';
    mysql_query ("$sql");
    print '<br /><br />tutto ok;<br /><br />';
?>
```

Is there anything that strikes being wrong? I got no error like database not found...

Comment: What are the errors that you see?

Comment: if I try to leave every thing as it it (msql commands), the program does not access the database and the site redirects me to the index page as it is supposed to in case of error in log in.
Is there a command I can use to prompt out error messages?

Comment: Please check the connection: 
`if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }`

Comment: added my original question... the answer is just "Could not connect to MySQL"

Comment: I might have found an error... if I run the debug using my previous Mysql commands (not the Mysqli commands) all works fine if I call directly the function. (see last bit of code). When I include the code then connection seems not to work. I am passing the name of the table in this way  

connectto('test');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some wondering around and splitting the problem in little subtasks, i believe I managed to understand that that little stupid extra comma in the list was preventig me to run the program, I copy pasted a syntax shared on-line and now everything seems to work...

outcome:
- check the spelling
- Isolate problems one by one...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing me slightly but you can connect using MySQLi using the following:

```
$link = new mysqli($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$tablename);
```

In your code you have

```
or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
```

Which says if you can not connect for whatever reason just print out this. You're not going to get any more information because you need to include $conn->connect_error e.g.

```
if ($link->connect_error) {die ("Failed: " . $link->connect_error);}
```

You should end up with something like

```
$tablename = "test";
$db_host = "xxx";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_pass = "xxx";
$link = new mysqli($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$tablename);
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die ("Failed: " . $link->connect_error);
} else { 
    echo " <br /><br />connection established! <br />";
}
```

Comment: I understand the confusion, My original question was if the use of mysql instructions rather than mysqli instructions could have caused the crush of my website once I load it in apache. After some playing around seems that if I leave with the mysql functions (I am quite new to mysqli) I can connect and update a counter in a dtabase but I still don`t manage to connect another table that I need for another part of my website. I believe at teh moment I got a connection issue where I need to close some mysql instances. I will try to figure this out by myself, I will close this post in a while. Tks